# Check if points are sorted in circular order

Tags: circles

How do you check if points are sorted in circular order (regardless of clockwise or counter-) (assuming they don't exactly form one whole circle, what matters is the points are sorted in a circular order)?

[image]

Comment: Presumably the points all lie on a common circle?

Comment: Also, how are the points specified? Do you have, say, $(x, y)$ coordinates for each of them?

Comment: yes, there are _(x,y)_ coordinates for each of them. They don't have to lie on a common circle. @Travis

Comment: If they don't lie on a common circle, what defines the reference point for determining circular order? Different choices of reference point will, in general, lead to different orders.

Comment: NB if the vertices are the vertices of a convex polygon (i.e., none of the points is in the interior of the convex hull of the remaining points), as is the case in the picture, then the order is the same for any reference point inside the polygon, but this is a strong restriction on the configurations of points.

Comment: @tjvg1991 That the points are specified by coordinates , seems to be an important point. Can you add it to your post? Also request you to address the answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $c$ be the barycenter of the points $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$. Then the points are  sorted in circular order when $ccw(c,p_i,p_{i+1}) > 0 $ for all $i$, with $p_{n+1}=p_1$. Here $ccw$ is the standard [geometric primitive](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/91primitives/).

Any point in the convex hull works as a center $c$. For instance, the lowest point among the given points.